# Why can't I use Tensorflow on Windows 7?

Tags: python, tensorflow, dll

I'm in trouble. I did my best and I'm still having problems with Tensorflow. I just wanted to use something, but I can't, and that makes me extremely frustrated. Who knows when I'll be able... Anyway, I'll tell you what happened, maybe some blessed soul will clear my doubts once and for all.

I have a Windows 7 notebook, my CPU apparently doesn't support AVX, and I don't have GPU. I tried to install two versions of tensorflow that don't require AVX. Obviously, one at a time, I didn't try to install both at the same time haha.

With python 3.6: tensorflow-1.5.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

When using this, an error appears: ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795.
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime

With python 3.7: tensorflow-1.11.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

When using this, an error appears: ImportError: DLL load failed with error code 3221225501.
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

That is, nothing worked.
Some settings on my PC:

Microsoft Windows 7 Professional,
Processor: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU 847 @ 1.10GHz, 1100 Mhz, 2 Cores, 2 Logic Processors,
System Type: x64-based PC,
Physical Memory (RAM): 4.00GB,

Please help me.

Comment: You're new to tensorflow, right? If that's true, immediately give up on `TF 1.x`.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan TF 2.X works with AVX instructions, doesn't it?

Comment: As far as I know, every TF version asserts your hardware capabilities and adjusts its execution accordingly. There are no hardware dependencies except having a nvidia gpu for `tensorflow-gpu`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Tensorflow cpu

```
pip install tensorflow-cpu
```

https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-cpu/

If it doesn't work you can try this repo https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel, it provides Legacy & low-end CPU (without AVX) support.

Comment: You really helped, even though you didn't get anything in return. Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry @RaulTeixeira, he got his 15 rep c: